# Async generator in Nodejs for recursively fetching promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, generator

I am trying to recursively scan a mysql table and process rows in batches.
`ids` is equivalent to array of rows and `promise1` fetch a chunk of rows and `promise2` process them. This is what I've implemented so far. This is working as expected. How can I improve it to simplify further?

```
const ids=[]
for(let i=0;i<50;i++){
    ids.push(i)
}
const promise1=(limit,after=-1)=>new Promise(r=>setTimeout(()=>r(ids.slice(after+1,after+limit+1)),1000))
const promise2=a=>new Promise(r=>setTimeout(()=>r(a.map(b=>b*2)),1000))
async function* promiseGen(){
    let limit=10
    let after=-1
    while(true){
        let pr1=await promise1(limit,after)
        if(pr1.length==0){
            break
        }
        yield pr1
        console.log(pr1)
        after=pr1[pr1.length-1]
    }
}
async function processor(){
    let pr1=promiseGen()
    let result=[]
    while(true){
        let data=await pr1.next()
        if(data.done){
            break
        }
        let res=await promise2(data.value)

        result.push(res)

    }
    return result
}

processor().then(res=>console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`for await … of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of):

```
async function processor() {
    const result = [];
    for await (const val of promiseGen()) {
        result.push(await promise2(val))
    }
    return result;
}
```